# Xcode Linker Error When using web service

Tags: ios, web-services, linker-errors

ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

What to do?

Comment: Go to your target -> Build Phase -> See compile sources and link library and check that no item mentioned is in red.

Comment: In the Copy Bundle Resources "main.storyboard" is mentioned in red. What to do?

Comment: No that will be in red only. Please check if any of your framework you added is missing from link libraries?

Comment: check this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266649/xctest-build-errors-for-test-target-xcode-5

Comment: Shruti I checked it .. All frameworks are available in link libraries.

Comment: Million upvotes if I could. This was the fix for me... Thanks

Comment: I will add that link as a answer. Please accept that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the link. It might help solving your problem. 
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266649/xctest-build-errors-for-test-target-xcode-5)