# Whats the alternative of @testable import in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctest, xcode7.3

I am working with Unit Testing in Xcode using XCTest provided by Xcode in objective C.
I know how to import Module in Swift like below.

---

```
@testable import  AppName
```

*Whats the alternative in objective C.*

Comment: Can't you just `#import` them? Or do you want to access private methods of Objective C?

Comment: @Tomer : Then i need to import all files to compile sources of UnitTestCase target which doesn't  seems to be good solution.

Comment: Your test target is linked against your main target. What do you need other than importing the .h?

Comment: @Jon Ried : UITests has different target,thats why i need to import app files to my ui testing target.

Comment: This is huge problem for mixed code, if you have an objc class that uses a swift class you can't test the objc class because the swift one is not included in tests, i don't know how could they not think of that. Did you find any solution except writing all tests in objc and include the files in the tests target? I tried to disable testability but i have some tests that load from nib and the classes have a different module name than when running the app, so it failes.

Answer (score 10):

`@testable` overrides access rights in Swift, allowing you to test `internal` methods in unit tests.

Objective-C has no such access modifiers, therefore you don't need `@testable` and you just import the module normally.

If you need to unit test internal Swift methods, you will have to write your tests in Swift.

Comment: According to Apple Documentation`Note: @testable provides access only for “internal” functions; “private” declarations are not visible outside of their file even when using @testable.`

Comment: @BabulPrabhakar All right, thanks, I have fixed that.

Answer (score 7):

In Objective C you can simply `#import` them, as there are no such "internal" method access limitations as in Swift.

Also, On Xcode 6 your main target should be already linked to the test target. If not, try to check the "Allow testing Host Application APIs" checkbox inside Your Test Target > General > Testing. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911168/when-do-app-sources-need-to-be-included-in-test-targets) for more information.

Comment: I have been working with Functional UI Testing where i have to mock Core-Data objects  which are used in app,therefore this solution will not work in my case.

Comment: Simply #import what? If the Swift files aren't in the test target, then they won't be in AppTest-Swift.h, and App-Swift.h isn't accessible when compiling the test target.

Comment: @Uncommon - add them to the test target and then they'll be included in the AppTest-Swift.h