# Objective c: XCTest with Core data class

Tags: objective-c, core-data, xctest

I have a custom Core Data class called `User`, but when I tried to import the `User+CoreDataClass.h` file in my XCTest, it says that the file is not found, and it does not even show up. I have tried to search but most of the results are for Swift and not Objective-C. Does anyone know how to fix this in Objective-C?

[image]

To add more information,

```
User* user1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:mainContext];
```

does not work because the User entity is not recognised.

Comment: Did you share your file with test target ?

Comment: Yes, I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911168/when-do-app-sources-need-to-be-included-in-test-targets and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140363/core-data-classes-not-generated-for-test-target and both do not seem to be working

Comment: Did you try the `@import` shown in that second answer? It's not in your screenshot.

Comment: Did u mean `@import "AppFileName"`? because it doesn't auto complete as well even though I've already set the test target to be testable