# mach-o-liinker error in xcode 5 upgrade

Tags: ios, xcode5

I upgraded to xcode 5 recently. When I try to run my app that is already working with xcode 4.6, i get this error:

ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/InterfaceBuilderKit.framework/InterfaceBuilderKit' for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Anyone know of a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you try to "Clean" your target first?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173626/apple-mach-o-linker-id-warning-building-for-macosx-but-linking-against-dyli

Answer (score 0):

This issue cause from your target setting that has been added automatically in Xcode 5.0

Try these

1. in your project target look for "Search Paths"->"Framework Search Paths" make sure the value for the field is empty.
2. in your project target look for "Linking"->"Other linker Flags" make sure the value is empty.

Hope it help