# Running Clang++ compiled file raises "dyld: mach-o, but built for simulator (not macOS)" after installing React-Native

Tags: xcode, clang++

After I installed React-Native.
Whenever build a file through "clang", I can't execute the file.
Always I got this message when try to execute it.

```
dyld: mach-o, but built for simulator (not macOS)
```

And I found that my default compile option of clang is changed for "ios-simulator".

How to change this default option?

```
$ clang++ --std=c++17 --verbose test_move.cpp
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-ios9.0.0-simulator -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name test_move.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -faligned-alloc-unavailable -target-sdk-version=12.2 -target-cpu core2 -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 450.3 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk -stdlib=libc++ -Wno-atomic-implicit-seq-cst -Wno-framework-include-private-from-public -Wno-atimport-in-framework-header -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-error --std=c++17 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/user/workspace/examples -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 149 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fobjc-runtime=ios-9.0.0 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/9k/c6qvlvt10wg3g5vyzf009lxw0000gn/T/test_move-3416bc.o -x c++ test_move.cpp
clang -cc1 version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4) default target x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
include "..." search starts here:
include <...> search starts here:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch x86_64 -ios_simulator_version_min 9.0.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk -o a.out /var/folders/9k/c6qvlvt10wg3g5vyzf009lxw0000gn/T/test_move-3416bc.o -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.ios.a
$
$
$ ./a.out
dyld: mach-o, but built for simulator (not macOS)
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Related: [Issue with executing a.out file (C++) MacOS Sierra 10.12.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39762289/issue-with-executing-a-out-file-c-macos-sierra-10-12-1)