# Xcode default gcc (mis)configured to compile for iOS instead of macOS

Tags: xcode, gcc, compiler-errors, dyld, mach

It appears Xcode 10.2.1 has broken my `gcc` installation. For example, if I try to compile a simple file:

```c
int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And run it I get:

```
dyld: mach-o, but built for simulator (not macOS)
Abort trap: 6
```

`gcc -v` is reporting back with:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

The option that jumps out there being:

--with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/**iPhoneSimulator.platform**/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1

I've recently installed the iOS simulator and I'm assuming doing so has lead to this. Is this expected behaviour? If not, is there any way I can get my `gcc` to compile for macOS again rather than iOS.

I've have tried deleting and reinstalling the Xcode Command Line Tools, to no avail. I imagine the solution is to completely uninstall and reinstall Xcode, which I'm a bit hesitant to do.

Comment: Mine reports `/MacOSX10.14.sdk/`. Try `xcode-select --install` (idea from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39762289/issue-with-executing-a-out-file-c-macos-sierra-10-12-1).

Comment: This was (part of) the method I used to reinstall the command line tools, which had no effect.

Comment: On reinstalling Xcode this issue remains ...

Comment: Mac version is 10.14.3 and the desired version of Xcode is ideally just the stable latest, so 10.2.1 I think!

Comment: Maybe try to update your system to macOS 10.14.5?

Comment: Related: [GCC with-gxx-include-dir is set to iOS 11.4 simulator](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329446/gcc-with-gxx-include-dir-is-set-to-ios-11-4-simulator)

Comment: So it's fixed although I don't currently have Xcode re-installed. Deleting everything, a reboot and then I need to `xcode-select --reset`, which has fixed it thus far. Now to ruin it all with Xcode. Thanks for you help!